# how to select both inputfields with getElementsByClass?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have 2 input fields and the autocomplete for places work only at one input field, I know that getElementById works only for 1 ID, I tried getElementsbyClass but that doesn't work.

How can I let it work at both input fields?

the html code

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<input id="autocomplete" name=origin type=text placeholder=Vertreklocatie>
<input id="autocomplete2" name=destination type=text placeholder=Bestemming>
```

js code

```
function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
    var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'nl'}};

    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjvWLE

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use getElementsByClassName, but you need to loop through the items

Here is an updated codepen. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvEpKx

```
function initialize() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete');
    var options = {componentRestrictions: {country: 'nl'}};

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputs[i], options); 
    }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete');
```

should work. it returns an array. so you have to loop through them, or get it by index i.e `[0]`